# The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

Tags: java

I'm compiling the Android projects in `Final Builder`.The following error occurs eventhough I have installed the `Java 64bit version`.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Program returned code  : 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase the heap size to a larger value?

Comment: I would go with decreasing the initial heap space: `The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.`

Comment: How to increase the heap size value?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you the jvm argument for heap size is too large.

Try a smaller value, for example `-Xms1024M`.

Comment: How to set the heap size?(min or max)

Comment: Well the `-Xms4096M` is setting it. This setting must be configured somewhere, most likely as part of a script or an environment variable. Have a good look around and you'll find it somewhere :)

Comment: My issue was knowing the setting, but wondering why it was invalid.  Found my Linux system of the `java` versions installed `alternative` set to using a 32-bit/i386 version for some reason.  Even uninstalling that removed the 64-bit openjdk version I had as well..  Reinstalling and configuring to that version again fixed it!